# Appcelerator Titanium: Authorization to get tweets

Tags: twitter, oauth, authorization, titanium, appcelerator

Does anyone know how to get tweets when you have to be authorized? I am able to post tweets, which is done by the oAuth Adaptor, but this doesn't have a GET method (only SEND).

I am trying to use the count parameter in the user_timeline. It doesn't require when i only use the SCREEN_NAME parameter, but when i use the COUNT parameter it needs authentication.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this. it's not my code, but maybe it helps. thanks @kosso (kosso@phreadz.com)

```
function getTweets(screen_name){

    // create table view data object
    var data = [];

    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.timeout = 1000000;  
    xhr.open("GET","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="+screen_name);

    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        try
        {
            var tweets = eval('('+this.responseText+')');

            for (var c=0;c<tweets.length;c++){

                var tweet = tweets[c].text;             
                var user = tweets[c].user.screen_name;
                var avatar = tweets[c].user.profile_image_url;
                var created_at = prettyDate(strtotime(tweets[c].created_at));

            }

        }
        catch(E){
            alert(E);
        }
    };
    // Get the data
    xhr.send();
```